# Submit form on page load

Tags: php, forms, authentication, form-submit

I want this login form to submit automatically when the page loads. I am using IP address for registration so do not want a login button.

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="ip_address" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Comment: You can use `submit()` method of JQuery.

Comment: Have you tried to use JavaScript ? On DOM load, submit the form.

Comment: first get the ip address and save it in the database, if saved header to the login page. on login page check if the actual ip is available in the database if  yes login -- go to member page, you dont need a  submit button.

Comment: The form's target resolves to itself, so you just have to login the user automatically and stop displaying the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<form id="my_form" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
     <input id="ip_address" type="hidden" name="ip_address" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($("#ip_address").val() != "")
        {
            $("#my_form").submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Note: you must add JQuery library in your web page.**

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST" id="my-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="ip_address" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<script>
    //Once the page is loaded, submit the form
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        //The id of your form.
        var idOfYourForm = "my-form";
        document.getElementById(idOfYourForm).submit();
    });
</script>
```

You just need to set the `id` attribute to your form and set the variable `idOfYourForm`, so the JavaScript will be able to submit your form. 
This method use pure JavaScript, no jQuery or other library.

See [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't use jQuery:

```
<body onload="javascript:submitonload();">
<form id="my_form" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="ip_address" value="<?=(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '');?>" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitonload() {
document.getElementById('my_form').submit();
}
</script>
</body>
```